# C - access the file with more pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I need to access the files with more pointers,
i know the function fread and i know what it does but i need something like that:
[image: access the file with more pointers]

And i have to be able to do something like this:
[image: move the pointer foward or back in the file data]

One way could be open 3 time with 3 different FILE pointers the same file (but i think it's a dirty work) so i would like to know if there is a way to read a file with multi-pointers and decide to switch to the next byte or to the back byte with the pointer that i want.

Comment: Use `ftell` to get a reference to the current position of a stream, and `fseek` to go back to that location later

Comment: If you want to access the same file through different `FILE` objects, that'll be at least non-portable. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @mafso: Is it really non-portable?  I assumed it would work everywhere, at least if you only do reading.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: It's implementation-defined (C11 7.19.3 p.8). I don't know, for what systems this doesn't work (and how important the systems where it doesn't are), though.

Comment: i need that because i'm implementing LZ77 algorithm so i need more pointer in the file to manage the buffer of the dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option 1: open the file multiple times

This is totally fine.  It's not dirty.  The operating system and standard library will keep everything straight for you (as long as you're not also *writing*).

### Option 2: read the entire file

This is also totally fine.  Most files are small and fit in memory, then you can just use ordinary pointers to point to memory locations.

### Option 3: memory map the entire file

On Unix-like systems, you can use `mmap()`.  This will put the entire file in your address space, but the OS will typically defer actual IO until you read from a particular page in the memory map.  This has most of the advantages of options 1 and 2, but it is slightly more complicated to work with, and you would need to write a separate version for Windows, because Windows doesn't have `mmap()` (it has something else, I forget what it's called).

### Option 4: seek back and forth

You can save your position with `ftell()` and then `fseek()` later to get back.

Comment: (You were thinking of [MapViewOfFile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087282/is-there-a-memory-mapping-api-on-windows-platform-just-like-mmap-on-linux).)

Comment: thank you... i think i will use the first option... because i'm implementing the LZ77 algorithm and with the option 1 (for me) is more easier